# Getting This Game to Work - Python Learn Python the hard way-Zed Shaw Ex43

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

print "NOVA"
print "Created by Zachary C. Boedeker "
print "Copyright 2016"
print "Start"

name = raw_input("What is your name?")
# This is for the player or user to input there name and alow them to have there name registerd later on.
print "okay %r , Would you like to join me?" % (name)
question = raw_input("Yes or no ?")

if raw_input == "yes" "y":
    print "Great, %r !" % (name)
    print "Are you ready %r ?" % (name)
    print "do you remamber anything ?"
    print "The Sky, The Stars, Earth, Home,The Accident ?"
    print "Anderson %r is still recovering im going back to the bridge call me if anything changes."
    print " HEY %r Can you hear me ?" % (name)
    print " %r you work as a space miner for NOVA." % (name)
    print "Nitro Omega Ventura Apollo."
    print "A top secret branch of the military."
    print " %r you have been assined the Apollo branch...or deep space opperations." % (name)
    print "That is all I can give you right now ."
    print "%r you took some damage but you should be fine." % (name)
    print "I think the medication is wearing off lets go back to the bridge."
    print "WARNING WARNING WARNING UNKNOW OBJECT IN .............."
    print "........................................................"
    print "........................................................."

# this is a issue as well doesnt want to let user decide yes or no
# I have yes but no doesnt work...  elif and else dont seem to work.They are comments because im trying to test out the beguining.
elif raw_input == "No" "no":
    print "Okay sorry for asking %r ....." % (name)
    print "Restart game to play...."
    print "Thanks for playing."
    exit(2)


class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        print "This is not yet configured.Subcllass it and implementeer()."
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

        def play(self):
            current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
            last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

            while current_scene != last_scene:
                next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
                current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

            # be sure to print out the last scene
            current_scene.enter()

class Death(Scene):

    quips = [
        "You died...Well now what do we do?",
        "Your mom would be so proud if you were smarter.",
        "Wish you had  lives?",
        "Can we try this again jsut this time dont die?"
    ]

    def enter(self):
        print Death.quips[randint(0,len(self.quips)-1)]
        exit(1)

class MedLab(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Your are in space on a deep space mining oppperation"
        print "You roll over still recovering from that crazy, Minning accident."
        print "The stiches still fresh in your side.The soaked bandages keep your blood from ozing out."
        print "I must get up ! I will get up!"
        print "The pain from your injury burns with every move you make."
        print "Standing on the icy floor pricks your feet"
        print "You need your suit, But you also what to know where the Doctor is?"
        print "Do you put on your spacesuit? Or walk out of the MedLab to find the doctor ?"

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "spacesuit" "Put on suit":
            print "It hurts to put on your spacesuit."
            print "LT %r is written on the Helemt." % (name)
            print "The helmet powers on and the lodading screen apperes."
            print "Lt %r its good to see your up and about." % (name)
            print "Downloading ships info."
            print "DAMAGE ALL CREW DEAD WARNING AIR LOCK BREACH IN Corridor."
            print "UNKNOWN LIFE-FORMS DETECTED.REQUESTED QUARENTENE."
            print "WARNING AUTO PILOT ENGAGED TIME TO LIGHTSPEED 5 HOURS TILL ARIVAL TO EARTH."
            print "The computer turns off and the light on your helmet turns on"
            print "Warning Air supply 50%"
            print "I need O2 thats in My Room,but I need to cancle the Auto-Piolt.What should I do ?"
            print "Exit out to the Corridor."

            return 'Corridor'

        elif action == "walk out of MedLab" "Find Doctor.":
            print "You open the door and get sucked out of the MedLab!!!!"
            print "WARNING BREACH AIR LOCK ERROR."
            print "You get the life sucked out of you."
            return 'death'

class Corridor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "The EMERGENCY LIGHTS and SIREN BLARES."
        print "The Anti-Gravity has been knocked out."
        print "LIFE-FORMS DETECTED ON LOWER LEVEL."
        print "The body of Dr.Anderson Floats lifeless."
        print "ACTIVATING MAGNETIC BOOTS.The lights show many scratch marks on the walls."
        print "The window has been broken and space is every where."
        print "The Sun and planet jupiter can be seen."
        print "What are we doing way out here? We where suppost to be going to mars."
        print "WARNING O2 Levels 40%"
        print "I should get more O2 in my room.But I need to Stop the Auto-Piolt."

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "Go to my Room" "Get O2" "My Room" "O2":

            return 'MyRoom'

        elif action == "Go to Bridge" "Bridge":
            return 'TheBridge'

class TheBridge(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "THE DOORS OPEN AND AN ALIEN JUMPS AT YOU!!!!!!"
        print "Its is covered in a slime and black as space."
        print "I looks you in the eye and lunges at you."
        print "Its Mouth goes to bite you!!!"
        print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                return 'death'

        elif action == "Push it" "Push it away from you":
                print "you push it away from you."
                print "you turn to run back into the Corridor but alas."
                print "your smiling into the mouth of ailen on the door."
                print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

        elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                print "It explodes all over the place"
                print "You enter the main control panel and pick up the access codes for the Reactor."
                print "NOVA"
                print "You can go to the Reactor now and arm to Reactor."
                print "Looking at the escape pods you see only one working that is Number 4."

                return 'Reactor'


class Reactor(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "The door to the Reactor is locked."
        print "input code"
        print "Are you sure you want to do this?"
        print "wrong 10 times then the lock closes forever and you can't"
        print "Enter the REACTOR.  The code is 3 digits."
        code = "%d%d%d" % (randint(1,9), randint(1,9), randint(1,9))
        guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")
        guesses = 0

        while guess != code and guesses < 10:
            print "BZZZZEDDD!"
            print "INCORRECT PIN"
            guesses += 1
            guess = raw_input("[keypad]> ")

        if guess == "code":
            print "Doors open and you walk into the Reactor."
            print "You open up the self-destruct system."
            print "WARNING WARNING THE SELFDESTRUCT SYSTEM IS BEING ARMED"
            print "WARNING WARNING TO DE-ACTIVATE SELF ESTRUCT PLEASES ALOT 2 MINIUTES."
            print "WARNING WARNING INPUT TIMER."
            print " %r is setting SELFDESTRUCT to 10 MINIUETS. "
            print "ALL CREWMEBERES REPORT TO ESCAPE PODS."
            print "Timer set 10 Miniutes to SELFDESTRUCT!"
            print "Were getting out of here"
            print "To the escape pods."
            print "Okay lets go."
            return 'Escapepods'

        else:
            print "THE ALARM ATTRACTS ALIENS !!!"
            print "WAHT DO YOU DO ?"
            print "HIT IT OR PUSH IT ?"
        if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                return 'death'

        elif action == "Push it" "Push it away from you":
                print "you push it away from you."
                print "you turn to run back into the Corridor but alas."
                print "your smiling into the mouth of ailen on the door."
                print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

        elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                print "It explodes all over the place"

                return 'Reactor'

class Escapepods(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Take what pod?"
        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "1":
                print "INPUT PASSWORD."

                if action == "1230" "Code" "Open":
                        print "INCORECT"
                        print "AN ALIEN APPERES!!!!"
                        print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                        if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                                print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                                print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                                return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"

                elif action == "Hoth" "hoth" "HOTH":
                    print "ACESS GRANTED"
                    print "%r were getting out of here!!!"
                    print "The air lock closes."
                    print "You buckle in and look up ITS AN ALIEN!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"
                    print "The Pod Detaches from the Nevada."
                    print "You get away and see the nevada destroyed."
                    print "You get ready for hypersleep opening your bed and getting in it."
                    print "You get in and close the tube shut."
                    print "An alien spore is inside of your filters for O2 and it slides into your pod."
                    print "You are a host, you dont know it."
                    print "%r you drift into space forever never to be found because you have been infected." (name)

                    return'death'

                if action == "2":
                    print "INPUT PASSWORD."

                if action == "1230" "Code" "Open":
                    print "INCORECT"
                    print "AN ALIEN APPERES!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"

                elif action == "Alderan" "alderean" "ALDERAN":
                    print "ACESS GRANTED"
                    print "%r were getting out of here!!!"
                    print "The air lock closes."
                    print "You buckle in and look up ITS AN ALIEN!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"
                    print "The Pod Detaches from the Nevada."
                    print "You take off your helmat"
                    print "Another alien gets you from behind."

                if action == "3":
                    print "INPUT PASSWORD."

                if action == "1230" "Code" "Open":
                    print "INCORECT"
                    print "AN ALIEN APPERES!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"

                elif action == "Mustafar" "mustafar" "MUSTAFAR":
                    print "ACESS GRANTED"
                    print "%r were getting out of here!!!"
                    print "The air lock closes."
                    print "You buckle in and look up ITS AN ALIEN!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"
                    print "The Pod is stuck on the Nevada."
                    print " The bomb goes off and you died"

                    return'death'

                if action == "4":
                    print "INPUT PASSWORD."

                if action == "1230" "Code" "Open":
                    print "INCORECT"
                    print "AN ALIEN APPERES!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"

                elif action == "Endor" "endor" "ENDOR":
                    print "ACESS GRANTED"
                    print "%r were getting out of here!!!"
                    print "The air lock closes."
                    print "You buckle in and look up ITS AN ALIEN!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"
                    print "The Pod Detaches from the Nevada."
                    print "Yes freedom!!!!"
                    print "The Nevada explodes destroying the alien. "
                    print "You go into hypersleep and wait to be rescued. "

                    return 'finished'

                if action == "5":
                    print "INPUT PASSWORD."

                if action == "1230" "Code" "Open":
                    print "INCORECT"
                    print "AN ALIEN APPERES!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"

                elif action == "NABOO" "Naboo" "naboo":
                    print "ACESS GRANTED"
                    print "%r were getting out of here!!!"
                    print "The air lock closes."
                    print "You buckle in and look up ITS AN ALIEN!!!!"
                    print "Hit It with your fists!!! or push it away from you!!!"

                if action == "Hit it" "Hit it with your fists" "Punch it":
                    print "It bites your arm and slithers into your suit."
                    print "Oh the slime it BURNS you feel it trurning you into soup."

                    return 'death'

                elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
                    print "It explodes all over the place"
                    print "The Pod Detaches from the Nevada."
                    print "You frogot to close the door."
                    print "you get sucked out into space."
                    print "You die in the cold dark space,"
                    " because in space no one can here you scream."

                    return'death'
class MyRoom(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "Your room is a mess %r" % (name)
        print "Hey thats your gun if you see any alien shoot them."
        print "Attatch the O2 tank to that pannel."
        print "O2 tanks being filled."
        print "Email from Captin dated almost 1 week ago."
        print "Read email or go to bridge?"

        action = raw_input("> ")

        if action == "read email" "Read":
            print "This is Captin Walker, We have a situation this email was writen up," 
            "to any salvagers or explores that may find the Nevada."
            "WE are infeced with an unidentified organiziam we think it may be sort of bacteria."
            "It can move in space and has the ability to cling to objects."
            "I am the sole suvivor abord...Our Lt %r Took a beating and Dr.Anderson fixed them up before,"
            "His death in experemnting with the unidentified alien."
            "We have changed the codes for the Reactor... and escape pods."
            "The password for the escape pod is 1.Hoth 2.Alderan 3.Mustafar 4.Endor 5.Naboo"
            "I have the Reactor password in the bridge but have been attaced by the alien."
            "We blew up the Corridor so I can not leave the room.Due to a broken helmet,"
            "I will die here tell my wife i loved her.-Captin Walker."
            print "Good info to know, Lets get out of here"

            return'Corridor'

        elif action == "Bridge" "Go to Bridge":

            return 'Corridor'

class finished(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "%r you live and get rescued."
        return 'finished'

class Map(object):

    scenes = {
    'MedLab': MedLab(),
    'Corridor': Corridor(),
    'TheBridge': TheBridge(),
    'Reactor': Reactor(),
    'Escapepods': Escapepods(),
    'MyRoom': MyRoom(),
    'death': Death(),
    'finished': finished(),
    }
    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        return val
    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('MedLab')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play(play)
```

there is a mistake in the code where it doesn't want to play. help please.i have no idea where the problem lies im sure it is with a_game.play(play) and somewhere in the Engine.But then again i am still learning.

Comment: What's the error message when you try to run it>???

Comment: We can't help you until you help us :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No one is going to dig through a 500-line code dump.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I see that will definitely stop your code form doing wht you want is this:

`if raw_input == 'yes' 'y':`

For one without using a list or other container for your strings, in that format they are concatenated so you are doing:

`if raw_input == 'yesy'`

The second issue is `raw_input` is a function not the value you got form it so in the end you have:

`if <built-in function raw_input> == 'yesy':`

This will never be `True`.

What you want is something like:

```
answer = raw_input(...)
if answer in ['yes', 'y']:
    do_stuff()
```

For something like this:

```
elif action == "Shoot it" "fire your gun":
```

You'll want:

```
elif any(['Shoot it' in action, 'fire your gun' in action]):
```

You will probably want to normalize your input by making it all lowercase because `'A' == 'a'` is `False`. I would suggest giving your user options or looking for fewer words and being more general because

```
>>> action = 'shoot your gun'
>>> any(['Shoot it' in action, 'fire your gun' in action])
False
```

A more robust way to do it would be to list the options for your user or only test for specific action words ex:

```
if any(['shoot' in action, 'fire' in action])
```

Comment: My hat is off to you, sir, for combing through all that code.

Comment: Thanks I am very new to all of this sorry for not responding quick enough. I never had any formal training just wanted to see if i could make something...I see how that could be the reason it does't works. Thanks for the Help IanAuld I'm actually trying to input the new changes in the computer as we speak.